# How to put xml files in a new separate folder?

Tags: android, directory

I have 30 xml files or layouts which i would like to place in a separate folder for convenience. Where should i create this folder and how can i retrieve those files? Thnx in advance.

Comment: did you at least google for an answer?

Comment: If they are layouts they should always be in the layouts folder.

Comment: @blackbelt : yes, i did. And there was no clear answer for this. And from the comments i can make out its not even possible. And was it you who gave it a -1??

Comment: @Adam : yes they are layouts. But i have like 30 of them for a different module. It would be a lot more convinient if i can put them in a separate folder. cant i create another folder in layout folder itself?

Comment: no I was not me. StackOverflow it is not your personal do this work for me. You should try to write down something and, you have any issue asking for help. At least read the SO faq

Answer (score 0):

You should not put layouts in a separate folder other than layouts folder.

Comment: yes they are layouts. But i have like 30 of them for a different module. It would be a lot more convinient if i can put them in a separate folder. cant i create another folder in layout folder itself?